# Issues with linking Javascript files with Node.js and HTML

Tags: javascript

I am making an application with node.js and I basically want render a canvas with node.js so I can access a json file on the server since you can't change client storage on browsers. To add on when running my files I get this weird syntax error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Further examination shows that my javascript files that I am requiring (see internals folder) are being overwritten with html, thus causing the error. My question is why is it overwritting only the files I am requiring from the html I am rendering? To add on I am running on a dynamic port (65535) and on a localhost (client). My code is [here](https://github.com/EppersonJoshua/graphics)

Answer (score 0):

Your node server is not serving your static files, it only serves one html.

You might need to set up a static file server like or programm you server to lookup GET /internals/render.js and scaleCanvas.js

You can use express for that, it has all this out of the box.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```js
var app, server,
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
 
app = express()
app.use(express.static(root + '/public'));
server = app.listen(port, host, serverStarted);
 
function serverStarted () {
    console.log('Server started', host, port);
    console.log('Root directory', root);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to exit...\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sending the `index.html` file for all requests in your [`app.js`](https://github.com/EppersonJoshua/graphics/blob/main/app.js) file, ignoring the request URL.

You need to properly serve the JS files. You can take a look here for more details: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/